# Как установить статус кода 200 после ошибки от Telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

У меня есть бот, который работает на вебхуке и отправляет некоторые запросы, они долго обрабатываются и бот получает ошибки по типу `Wrong response from the webhook: 523` или `Read timeout expired`, затем телеграм пытается несколько раз заново обработать запросы, из-за чего они копятся и лишний раз срабатывают

Я хочу после получения таких ошибок вернуть 200 код, чтобы Телеграм не пытался заново отправить запрос:

```
// Здесь создается первоначальный запрос
$curl = curl_init($settings->url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Здесь отлавливаются ошибки с вебхука
$webhook_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN . '/getWebhookInfo';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webhook_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json_result = json_decode($result, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
switch ($json_result['result']['last_error_message']) {
    case 'Wrong response from the webhook: 523 ':
        send_message($chat_id, 'Бот поймал 523 ошибку');
        http_response_code(200);
    break;
    case 'Read timeout expired':
        send_message($chat_id, 'Время ожидания истекло');
        http_response_code(200);
    break;
}
curl_close($ch);
curl_close($curl);
```

Я попытался с помощью `http_response_code(200)` вернуть 200 код, бот заходил в нужные `case` при ошибках и выводил информацию о них, но ошибки не перестали приходить

Comment: Чтот вы какуюто фигню пытаетесь делать :) как по вашему работают вебхуки в телеграмм?

Comment: Попробуйте передать параметры: pending_update_count  и last_error_message